# PHP variable in bootstrap modal via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php page that lists a bunch of id's from a database. I then have a button next to each id that will open a Twitter Bootstrap modal window in the page and I need to pass the php variable to that model window so that I can do a mysql query in it.

My issue is the model window is just displaying the textbox I setup that should be showing the unique id. However instead it is showing the textbox with just a "null" in it.

My code is below
  The link used to trigger the Modal window. Note I confirmed that the link below does show the value for the php variable.

```
<a href='#switch_modal' class='btn btn-default btn-small' data-toggle='modal' data-id='$scommentid'>REPLY</a>
```

Ajax code to get the php variable into the Modal window

```
 <!-- get the unique comment id to use in the modal window -->
  <script>                     
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#switch_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');                                                                                                  
                $.ajax({
                          type : 'post',
                          url : 'fetch_comment_id.php', //Here you will fetch records 
                          data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
                          success : function(data)
                            {
                                 $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
                            }
                         });
                     });
                  });
  </script>
```

This is my modal window code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="switch_modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="fetched-data"></div>  
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my fetch_comment_id.php file

```
  <?php
    $id = $_POST['rowid']; //I know I need to clean this variable
    echo "# <input type='text' name='acommentid' value='$id'>";
  ?>
```

Comment: We need more clarity.

Comment: OK so think of the page I am trying to make as an email inbox. on that inbox type php / mysql page I have a listing of message names and message id's which I am pulling from a database. Thats all good and well. Now I also have a button on each row that essentially will open a Twitter Bootstrap Modal window where I intend to display the message the user clicked on in. So I need a way when you click the link I have in my message above to use ajax to get the value of data-id in my a href link into my modal window

Comment: I am still looking for suggested solutions to this issue anyone :(

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle or jsbin to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I think that would help everyone understand the problem. It sounds like you could create this example without PHP by mocking up the HTML that PHP is creating.

Comment: OK so take a look at
https://jsbin.com/nubijavule/edit?html,output

This is an html mockup of what I am trying to do. Each button's "data-id" has a unique id pulled from a mysql database and I need to use that unique id from which ever button is clicked in the modal window

Comment: What happens if you change `var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');` to `var rowid = $(this).attr("data-id");` just out of curiosity? What jquery version do you have?

Comment: If I change var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
to
var rowid = $(this).attr("data-id");
alert(rowid);
I then get undefined. Also I am using Jquery on Google CDN  version 2.2.0

Comment: the error has to be somewhere else. i just rebuilt this setup and everything works fine here. you should try to debug your code. for example after `var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); ` do `alert(rowid);` to see if you get the rowid from your javascript code. or in your PHP code change `$id = $_POST['rowid'];` to `$id = $_REQUEST['rowid'];`. then open it in your browser, passing the variable in the url: `fetch_comment_id.php?rowid=1234` and see what the PHP script returns.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
```

to

```
var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
```

Your code should look like this:

```
  $('#switch_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      url : 'fetch_comment_id.php', //Here you will fetch records 
      data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
      success : function(data) {
        $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
      }
    });
  });
```

You can see a demo of this working below. Please note that I passed the `rowid` to the `html()` instead of `data` to show that it is correctly passing the value.

https://jsfiddle.net/29wtk0gu/2/

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Replace data-id attribute assigned in anchor tag with following :

```
 data-id='<?php echo $scommentid; ?>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shivani Patel however the line that data-id='' is wrapped in a <?php echo""; ?> tag. So the data-id= does contain the correct value when I view the pages source. My issue is the fetch_comment_id.php file does not seem to me getting the value of the data-id so I am not sure if it is my javascript/ajax that is wrong or the fetch_comment_id.php  file